# Flutter integration with Firebase error on IOS (can't install pod)

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

I'm trying to add firebase to my new flutter project and I have followed the guides ([here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#3), and the other official guides by flutter and firebase)

As soon as I add the cloud_firestore to my dependencies I can't compile the project

This is my `pubspec.yaml` file

```
name: homemanagement
description: A new Flutter application.

publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.0+1

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

This is `Podfile`

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def parse_KV_file(file, separator='=')
  file_abs_path = File.expand_path(file)
  if !File.exists? file_abs_path
    return [];
  end
  generated_key_values = {}
  skip_line_start_symbols = ["#", "/"]
  File.foreach(file_abs_path) do |line|
    next if skip_line_start_symbols.any? { |symbol| line =~ /^\s*#{symbol}/ }
    plugin = line.split(pattern=separator)
    if plugin.length == 2
      podname = plugin[0].strip()
      path = plugin[1].strip()
      podpath = File.expand_path("#{path}", file_abs_path)
      generated_key_values[podname] = podpath
    else
      puts "Invalid plugin specification: #{line}"
    end
  end
  generated_key_values
end

target 'Runner' do
  # Flutter Pod

  copied_flutter_dir = File.join(__dir__, 'Flutter')
  copied_framework_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Flutter.framework')
  copied_podspec_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Flutter.podspec')
  unless File.exist?(copied_framework_path) && File.exist?(copied_podspec_path)
    # Copy Flutter.framework and Flutter.podspec to Flutter/ to have something to link against if the xcode backend script has not run yet.
    # That script will copy the correct debug/profile/release version of the framework based on the currently selected Xcode configuration.
    # CocoaPods will not embed the framework on pod install (before any build phases can generate) if the dylib does not exist.

    generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Generated.xcconfig')
    unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
      raise "Generated.xcconfig must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
    end
    generated_xcode_build_settings = parse_KV_file(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    cached_framework_dir = generated_xcode_build_settings['FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR'];

    unless File.exist?(copied_framework_path)
      FileUtils.cp_r(File.join(cached_framework_dir, 'Flutter.framework'), copied_flutter_dir)
    end
    unless File.exist?(copied_podspec_path)
      FileUtils.cp(File.join(cached_framework_dir, 'Flutter.podspec'), copied_flutter_dir)
    end
  end

  # Keep pod path relative so it can be checked into Podfile.lock.
  pod 'Flutter', :path => 'Flutter'

  # Plugin Pods

  # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.
  system('rm -rf .symlinks')
  system('mkdir -p .symlinks/plugins')
  plugin_pods = parse_KV_file('../.flutter-plugins')
  plugin_pods.each do |name, path|
    symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', name)
    File.symlink(path, symlink)
    pod name, :path => File.join(symlink, 'ios')
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

The issue is that when I try to run the app in my IOS simulator (iPhone 11 pro max)
the process gets stuck on `Running pod install...`

I have tried to clear cache with `flutter pub cache repair` and to reinstall with `pod install`
but it always gets stuck on `Installing gRPC-Core (1.28.0)`

I have tried to find the issue in Google but couldn't find a solution

P.S:
Works fine on Android

Comment: Can you add the logs from `CocoaPods`? just going to the iOS folder and run `pod install`.

Comment: Also, try to do `pod update` if you are still stuck in `pods install`.

Comment: @SagiShmuel already tried to run pod update and got stuck and got stuck again with pods install

The logs are stuck on Installing gRPC-Core (1.28.0)

Comment: I've found a workaround by deleting the the  gRPC-Core directory from ios/Pods and copying from repo in Github( a working one) and then run pod update and its working now...

Comment: @Yuri i have the same problem, how did you do that? To add the dependency to the Pod from github in Flutter? :O

Comment: I'm having the same problem. how do i fix it? @Yuri

Comment: When got stuck at grPC-Core, I cancelled the pod install command, and deleted this directory: /Users/<my-user>/Library/Caches/CocoaPods, then ran `pod repo update` and `pod install` again. Another useful solution that I've found when running into this kind of cocoapod problems can be found here: https://github.com/react-native-community/upgrade-support/issues/153#issuecomment-967002118

Answer (score 3):

I resolved it by deleting all the cache related to gRPC at `/Users/<user>/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/` and `.../Specs/Release/`, and running `pod install` again.

Answer (score 2):

This happens as you have to
.download ios tools,
.ios-profile tools,
.ios release tools

Run:
flutter precache --ios

now run:
pod install

everything will work fine.